# List user and group from an OU in AD

Tags: c#, active-directory, ou

I want to list all users and group from an OU in AD, and differenciate them. But I found solutions to list user or group, but not both of them. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the users separately and the groups. After that put them in a list or any collection.

I think a good way would be to create a class to put all objects with a name, type of object, etc... then you could add these classes to a list, sort the list and loop through it to show them in a mixed way.

Is that what you want? Or you have to reword your question.